# How to display something from an array depending on users choice

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a PHP program that has `Select HTML` options and an array with measurement. I would like to display a specific measure depending on the selection that they have made from the `Select` tag. [Here is a picture of how I set up my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfJ9z.png). 
 In addition, I have included a picture of all the selection options [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJDIL.png).

```
$sizeInches = array('3/4" x 1-1/2"', '3/4” x 2-1/2”','3/4” x 3-1/2”', '3/4” x 4-1/2”', '3/4” x 5-1/2”', '3/4” x 6-1/4”', '3/4” x 7-1/4”', '3/4" x 9-1/4"', '3/4" x 9-1/4"', '3/4" x 11-1/4"', '1-1/2" x 3-1/2"', '1-1/2" x 5-1/2"', '1-1/2" x 7-1/4"', '1-1/2" x 9-1/4"', '1-1/2" x 11-1/4"', '2-1/2" x 5-1/2"', '3-1/2" x 3-1/2"', '3-1/2" x 5-1/2"');
```

**Overall what I want it to do is if a user selects the `2" x 12"` option I would like for it to retrieve the proper measurement from the array, which would be `1-1/2" x 11-1/4`** [Here is what I would like it to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L04zC.png).

Currently this is how I have my `Select` tag setup

```
  <label> What size of lumber would you want?
      <select name="size" required>
        <option value="NULL"selected> -------- </option>
        <option value="1"> 1" X 2" </option>
        <option value="2"> 1" X 3" </option>
        <option value="3"> 1" X 4" </option>
        <option value="4"> 1" X 5" </option>
        <option value="5"> 1" X 6" </option>
        <option value="6"> 1" X 7" </option>
        <option value="7"> 1" X 8" </option>
        <option value="8"> 1" X 10" </option>
        <option value="9"> 1" X 12" </option>
        <option value="10"> 2" X 4" </option>
        <option value="11"> 2" X 6" </option>
        <option value="12"> 2" X 8" </option>
        <option value="13"> 2" X 10" </option>
        <option value="14"> 2" X 12" </option>
        <option value="15"> 3" X 6" </option>
        <option value="16"> 4" X 4" </option>
        <option value="17"> 4" X 6" </option>
      </select>
    </label>
```

***You guys may see that I have two submit buttons but for right now I'm trying to make sure that the `inch` one works first.***

Let me know if you guys need more information or would like me to edit something.
 
 Thank you for taking the time to try to help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you submit the value of the select, you can then use it as the index of the array to retrieve the correct result from the array. It would look something like this.

```
<?php
//value of the select
$selectValue = $_POST['size'];
//your array with all possible values
$sizeInches = array('3/4" x 1-1/2"', '3/4” x 2-1/2”','3/4” x 3-1/2”', '3/4” x 4-1/2”', '3/4” x 5-1/2”', '3/4” x 6-1/4”', '3/4” x 7-1/4”', '3/4" x 9-1/4"', '3/4" x 9-1/4"', '3/4" x 11-1/4"', '1-1/2" x 3-1/2"', '1-1/2" x 5-1/2"', '1-1/2" x 7-1/4"', '1-1/2" x 9-1/4"', '1-1/2" x 11-1/4"', '2-1/2" x 5-1/2"', '3-1/2" x 3-1/2"', '3-1/2" x 5-1/2"');
        $displayResult = '';
        //traverse the array and find the selected index, after that break out of loop
        for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $sizeInches ); $i++ ) {
            if ( $i === (int)$selectValue ) {
                $displayResult = $sizeInches[ $i ];
                break;
            }
        }
    ?>
    //display your result
    <h2> <?php echo $displayResult; ?></h2>
```

I hope this helps you !

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $selectValue=$_POST['size'];
    $displayResult = '';
    foreach($sizeInches as $Inches )
    {
        if( $Inches== $selectValue ) 
        {
            print_r($Inches);
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```